# In R 3.5 blogdown:::serve_site() cannot render .Rmd file

Tags: blogdown

After I updated R to 3.5, I found I couldn't render `.Rmd` file. I tried to reinstall the relevant packages, but it seemed it didn't solve the problem. More specifically, the error message is:

> blogdown:::serve_site()
>
> > Rendering content/post/mypost.Rmd
> >
> > Fatal error: cannot open file 'C:/Users/John': No such file or directory
> >
> > Error in render_page(f) : 
> >     Failed to render 'content/post/mypost.Rmd'

My blogdown.Rproj is under the folder `C:\Users\John Smith\Documents\GitHub\blogdown`. I am not sure why the path in the error message only shows `cannot open file 'C:/Users/John'`, the remaining part of the path was missing. Note the space in "**John Smith**"

Your help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ran into the same problem as [Is this a bug in R 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50028090/559676), and [I just applied a workaround](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/82c1fab548aa094afce7751d9b4a706daa7733d8) in the devel version of **blogdown**:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem and the pointer to a broader issue. Now the file got rendered successfully, and the resulted .html is fine, too. A minor issue is the viewer is empty. Did I miss anything?

Comment: How about refreshing the viewer? (Hit the refresh button on the top right)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The refresh button seems not working. Actually all the buttons are disabled under the viewer tab.

Comment: Can you restart R, `update.packages(ask = F); devtools::install_github('yihui/servr')`, and retry `blogdown::serve_site()`?

Comment: Nope, the viewer is still empty... Another difference I noticed is that when I saved the edits, the .Rmd was no longer automatically rendered. Previously if I ran `blogdown::serve_site()`, subsequently the file would be automatically rendered when I save the file. In any case, thank you for the help.

Comment: Weird. If you are using the latest version of RStudio and the problem persists, I can chat with you directly with screensharing to investigate the issue if that is a possible option for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for being willing to help. One more piece of information: I created another blogdown project, and tried `blogdown::serve_site()`. This time the Viewer worked well. I am not sure whether it is because I accidentally changed some setup I was unaware. Surely I look forward to investigating the issue by chatting with you directly :)

Comment: That is even more weird... Does `blogdown::build_site()` provide any useful information? You can also open a separate R session (not in RStudio), and run `blogdown::serve_site()` on the directory of your website.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The error from using RGui is indeed more informative. I realized that I saved a "geoMap.csv" data under `blogdown\data`. After I removed the data from the data folder, everything is fine including the Viewer problem in RStudio.

Comment: Here is the essence of the error message (due to the words limit). When I ran `blogdown::serve_site()`, the error shows: Failed to read data from geoMap.csv\geoMap.csv: Data not supported for extension 'csv'... Error: Error building site: logged 1 error(s)
'C:\Users\John' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) : 
  '"C:\Users\John Smith\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" -b / -D -F -d "public" -t hugo-academic' execution failed with error code 1

Comment: I see. The reason you didn't see the error message in RStudio was because RStudio had a bug: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2248 It has been fixed in the daily build. I think we are all set now.

Comment: Yup, we are all set now. Many thanks for the guidance.