# .Rmd posts do not render in Blogdown using 'wowchemy/starter-academic' in multilingual configuration

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I installed via Rstudio a Blogdown using 'wowchemy/starter-academic' theme (aka hugo-academic).
I changed to put the multilingual configuration in `language.tom`.
And I put the initial folders `home` and `post` in the folders `content/en` and `content/es`

```
[en]
  languageCode = "en-us"
  contentDir = "content/en"  # Uncomment for multi-lingual sites, and move English content into `en` sub-folder.

# Uncomment the lines below to configure your website in a second language.
[es]
  languageCode = "es-ES"
  contentDir = "content/es"
```

However, I use the addin `blogdown:::serve_site()` to render the site but I obtain systematically this error for the `.Rmd` posts:

```
WARN 2020/12/01 20:25:25 Alert shortcode will be deprecated in future. Use Callout instead. Rename `alert` to `callout` in "post/writing-technical-content/index.md"

ERROR 2020/12/01 20:25:25 [en] REF_NOT_FOUND: Ref "en/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown/index.html": "/Users/fabio/Desktop/BLog/Test 3 blogdown/content/en/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown/index.html:9:14": page not found
```

I tested to the options: [In R 3.5 blogdown:::serve_site() cannot render .Rmd file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077412/)

Maybe I am missing something, any help is really appreciated
Thanks @Yihui anyway for the great rmarkdown and blogdown package

my configuration:
HUGO_VERSION = "0.79.0"

```
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
 os       macOS Catalina 10.15.7      
 system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Paris                
 date     2020-12-01                  

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package   * version  date       lib source                            
 base64enc   0.1-3    2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 BH          1.72.0-3 2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 blogdown    0.21.48  2020-12-01 [1] Github (rstudio/blogdown@ece8b58) 
 bookdown    0.21     2020-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 digest      0.6.27   2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 evaluate    0.14     2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 glue        1.4.2    2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 highr       0.8      2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 htmltools   0.5.0    2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 httpuv      1.5.4    2020-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 jsonlite    1.7.1    2020-09-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 knitr       1.30     2020-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 later       1.1.0.1  2020-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 magrittr    2.0.1    2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 markdown    1.1      2019-08-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 mime        0.9      2020-02-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 promises    1.1.1    2020-06-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 R6          2.5.0    2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 Rcpp        1.0.5    2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 rlang       0.4.9    2020-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 rmarkdown   2.5.3    2020-12-01 [1] Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@beed481)
 servr       0.20     2020-10-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 stringi     1.5.3    2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 stringr     1.4.0    2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                    
 tinytex     0.27     2020-11-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 xfun        0.19     2020-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)                    
 yaml        2.2.1    2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
```

Comment: the problem is the output html file that .Rmd generate with the `en/` path . If I delete manually this path, it works. `<script src="{{< relref "en/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown/index.html" >}}index_files/header-attrs/header-attrs.js"></script>` 
I looked some other issues is related to miltilingual https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64688201/, but I don't think it is related

Comment: Sounds like a bug of **blogdown**. I'll take a look. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I have been checking the recent commits on the blogdown... However, I am having the same issue..  in anycase.. thank you for the wonderfull work with Rmarkdown Yihui :)

Comment: Sorry I haven't started working on this issue yet, but definitely will!

Comment: Take your time Yihui !! Thanks a lot !! :)

Answer (score 0):

This issue [has been resolved](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/11fec4c7d59234596501c36ceece72c5f6d2a0a0) in the current [development version of **blogdown**](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown):

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

Restart R, delete `content/en/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown/index.html`, run `blogdown::serve_site()` again, and the error should be gone.

Comment: Yess, The error is gone!!.. Thanks you very much Yihui.
Wishing you a Merry Christmas for you !!  All the best ! and thank you for your engagement in open source development !! :) :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting me know and the kind words! Happy holidays!